# How to get the "Real" TimeZone of browser with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I need the real timezone ID but NOT of fake / generic timezone like Etc/GMT-xxx.
I understand that there are some solution to get the offset, or even the "fake" timezone, with the commands:

`int offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
 String timezone = TimeZone.createTimeZone(offset).getID();`

And currently our project is using this. However, this will only give you the summarized offset, but you will never know if this offset actually contains the DST (Daylight Saving Time / Summer Time) offset. Or in other words : you know the total offset is 2 hours, but it wont tell if its actually 2 + 0, or 1 + 1, and it really does matter in my use case.

Here is our use case : We have a function that allow user to upload excel file, where the function will parse the excel file and insert the records into system. Each of the record will have different Date Time. Our function have to check the below:

1. If the browser TimeZone (from where the user upload the file) subject to DST_offset.
2. If it set subject to DST, we then further decide if the Date is fall under "summer".
3. Our system then offset the date time and store into DB accordingly.
4. So, inside a batch excel file, the multiple records there some may have DST Offset while some may not.

I understand that we can use the java Calendar to achieve the above logic 1 & 2, from this link https://www.baeldung.com/java-daylight-savings. But however, the pre-requisite is : we need the real timezone ID e.g. "Europe/Rome", but not the fake or general one "Etc/GMT-xxx".

Please advise how could we get the "real" timezone ID in Smart GWT? or if any alternative to handle the mentioned use case?

Comment: Join the GWT community here https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt you might get answers for your GWT questions

Answer (score 1):

I added `ZoneId.systemDefault()` a few days ago to https://github.com/adrianmsmith/gwt-time which hopefully should do exactly what you want. It returns the zone like “Europe/Rome”, from the browser, if the browser makes this info available (IE does not, for example). Feel free to reach out to me via my email address on my github account if you have any issues.